# How to get rid of this error Failed processing manifest?

Tags: android-studio

I got the above error when I changed `minsdk` to 21 and `targetsdk` to 23 both from API 26. It also shows some warnings like `minsdkVersion` (28) is greater than `targetsdkversion` (23) for variant release. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are two `build.gradle` files that you need to make sure their version is the same as your `AndroidManifest.xml`, one is in root directory of the project, which should be having lines containing `defaultMinSdkVersion` and `defaultTargetSdkVersion`. The other is inside your app directory and it shouldn't have any of such lines. After changing those make sure you do a clean build again.

Comment: I checked everything as you said. but problem was not in my project It was in Android Studio. I roll back to Api 26 then lowered the Api level by level and refreshed the gradle accordingly. And it helped. btw thanks for your answer.